# Error en Android desde un Login (MainActivity) a un AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IFragments

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando pasar de mi MainActivity que es mi Login a una ventana que contiene una lista de distintos fragments, pero cuando ingreso mis datos en el Login y le doy al botón "Ingresar", ésta lanza la otra actividad y la aplicación se cierra (android studio).

He intentado con estas dos formas y las dos me cierran la aplicación cuando doy al botón Ingresar... Ayúdenme por favor.

1. Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inicio.class); startActivity(i);
2. Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inicio.class); MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

---

Este es mi MainActivity donde está el login

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText txtCor, txtPas;
Button btnIngresar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCor = findViewById(R.id.txtCor);
    txtPas = findViewById(R.id.txtPas);

    btnIngresar = findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Thread tr=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String res=enviarPost(txtCor.getText().toString(), txtPas.getText().toString());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int r=objJSON(res);
                            if (r>0){
                                //Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inicio.class);
                                //startActivity(i);
                                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Inicio.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            tr.start();

        }
    });
}
public String enviarPost(String cor, String pas) {
    String parametros = "cor=" + cor + "&pas=" + pas;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String respuesta = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.10/WebService/valida.php");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(parametros.getBytes().length));

        // con esto se indica que salen algunos datos (parametros)
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(parametros);
        wr.close();

        Scanner inSteam = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());

        while (inSteam.hasNextLine())
            respuesta += (inSteam.nextLine());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return respuesta.toString();
}

public int objJSON(String rspta) {
    int res = 0;
    try {
        JSONArray json=new JSONArray(rspta);
        if(json.length()>0)
            res=1;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return res;
}
```

}

---

Este es mi archivo style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

---

Este es mi Logcat

```html
02-24 10:56:08.385 9361-9361/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-24 10:56:08.765 9361-9361/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-24 10:56:08.977 9361-9361/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-24 10:56:09.216 9361-9385/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
02-24 10:56:09.223 9361-9361/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-24 10:56:09.283 9361-9385/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                             OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.01
                                             Build Date: 01/29/15 Thu
                                             Local Branch: 
                                             Remote Branch: 
                                             Local Patches: 
                                             Reconstruct Branch: 
02-24 10:56:09.286 9361-9385/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-24 10:56:09.303 9361-9385/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-24 10:56:09.392 9361-9361/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3a189687 time:310770737
02-24 10:56:26.956 9361-9361/com.example.matias.taken W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
02-24 10:56:30.362 9361-9361/com.example.matias.taken I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.matias.taken time:310791706
02-24 10:56:30.936 9361-9361/com.example.matias.taken D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-24 10:56:30.937 9361-9361/com.example.matias.taken E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.matias.taken, PID: 9361
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.taken/co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                            at co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:31)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

### 02-24 10:56:30.943 9361-9361/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9361 SIG: 9

Este es mi manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/><!--- para usar la camara desde la App -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/><!--escribir en memoria para guardar las fotos -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/><!--leer las imagenes guardadas en la galeria -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <activity android:name=".Inicio" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Para agregar información a tu pregunta se realiza mediante el boton "editar". Te sugiero agregar que error se muestra en el LogCat.

Comment: el logcat menciona problema con el Action Bar. Como tienes en el manifest en android:theme de la activity inicio? es el mismo que esta en styles?

Comment: Arriba agregue mi manifest Armen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando un Navigation Drawer, lo mas probale es que el
layout del DrawerLayout tenga un widget.`Toolbar`, el cual se inicializa en `onCreate`
de tu activity Inicio, por lo tanto en el `manifest` debes de declarar 
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`  ó

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

de esa activity y en styles debes de tener algo así:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/HamburguesaIcon</item>
    </style>
```

En tu caso tienes que declarar el tema en el manifest:

```
<activity 
android:name=".Inicio" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, esto me soluciono el problema. Saludos y que tengas buen día!